# Error Installing xubuntu

Tags: boot, live-usb

I am trying to Install xubuntu minimal amd 64. Iam using ventoy  for installing. But when I press "try or install Ubuntu" I only see a _ blinking on black screen. After like 10 mins I get an error on screen.
'End kernel panic attempted to kill init! Exit code 0×00007f00'

Comment: You've not provided any release details; but from details you've provided I'd suggest it was an invalid ISO (*did you verify it?*) or a ventoy issue due to incorrect setup.

Comment: Please tell us more about what you have: Brand name and model of the computer and version of Xubuntu (22.04.x LTS?). Are you running Ventoy in Windows or MacOS or in some Linux version?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot)